# How to display List as a table with c# and WinForms

Tags: c#, list, winforms, class

I have a List in a class that look like this.

```
public  class Festival
{
    public string _festivalName;
    public int _showCap = 5;
    public List<Show> setList = new List<Show>();

    public Festival()
    {
        
    }

    public void createFestival(Festival z)
    {
        
        Show x = new Show();
        x.setFestival(z);
    }
    
  
    public void addShow(Band y)
    {
        
        setList.Add(y); 

    }

    public void addShow(Preformer x)
    {
        Preformer y = new Preformer(x);
        setList.Add(y);

    }
 }
```

The Prefomer class for example look like this:

```
public class Preformer: Show
{

    public bool _gotEncore;
    public Preformer(string bandName,string bandHit)
    {
        
        this._bandName = bandName;
        this._bandHit = bandHit;
        
    }

    public Preformer(Preformer t)
    {

    }

    ~Preformer() { }

    public void setEncore(bool gotEncore)
    {
        _gotEncore = gotEncore;
    }
}
```

The Base class is Show and the child are Band and Performer.
In the class Festival, i have a list of Shows and I want to show all the details of each performer/ band that in List in a dynamic styled table.

Thank You!

Comment: I think a `ListView` is what you want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: You may want to look into the 'DataGridView' control : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean Performer, not Preformer. You might want to get that right before release.